# How to combine two list of lists to a new list

Tags: python, list

I have a problem like this. I have two lists, A and B, where `A=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` and `B=[["a","b"],["c","d"]]`, I would like to got a new list from these two like

```
C = [
     [[1,2],["a","b"]],
     [[3,4],["a","b"]],
     [[1,2],["c","d"]],
     [[3,4],["c","d"]]
    ]
```

I had try the following code:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B=[["a","b"],["c","d"]]
for each in A:
    for evey in B:
        print each.append(evey)
```

However, the output is None.

Any helpful information are appreciated. Thank you.

By the way, I had try to replace the "append" with simple "+". The output is a list which elements are not list.

Comment: You're printing the return value of `append`, which is `None`.

Comment: Where did `[5,6]` from `A` go?

Answer (score 2):

This was answered here: [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

Try this:

```
import itertools

A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
C = []

for element in itertools.product(A,B):
    C.append(list(element))

print C
```

Comment: If you think the question is a duplicate, vote to close it.

Comment: Since it is a duplicate, then why you answer it?

Comment: @FallenAngel: I don't have enough points to vote it as duplicate (and I'm new here).

Comment: Welcome, it was all documented in the help files. In [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) you can find related parts. It is not expected from the new comers to read all the help section, but it will be great to check there and learn the basics of the site.

Comment: Thank you. I will make use of that links! Also, the OP might have not known that this is actually a Cartesian product related question...

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B=[["a","b"],["c","d"]]
C = zip(A,B)
```

The output here is a list of tuples:

```
[([[1, 2], [3, 4]],), ([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']],)]
```

If you want a list of lists, you can do this:

```
D = [list(i) for i in zip(A, B)]
```

The output:

```
[[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']], [[3, 4], ['c', 'd']]]
```

Comment: zip function doesn't solve the problem. It shows `[([1, 2], ['a', 'b']), ([3, 4], ['c', 'd'])]`

Comment: Thanks for your help. As @vasilenicusor said it may need a iteration to produce the result I want.  Actually, I find another very simple way to solve it. Just using : C= [x,y, for x in A for y in B]

Comment: @ThomasDing it seems that the second output in my answer `D` which is this `[[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']], [[3, 4], ['c', 'd']]]` is what you wanted. BTW: have you tested your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to append each couple of elements in each iteration.

```
result = []
for each in A:
    for evey in B:
        result.append([each,evey])
>>>result
[[[1, 2], ['a', 'b']],
 [[1, 2], ['c', 'd']],
 [[3, 4], ['a', 'b']],
 [[3, 4], ['c', 'd']]]
```

**OR**

simply use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>>from itertools import product   
>>>list(product(A,B))
[([1, 2], ['a', 'b']),
 ([1, 2], ['c', 'd']),
 ([3, 4], ['a', 'b']),
 ([3, 4], ['c', 'd'])]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The problem solved. I confused myself by the append method. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't print return value of append(), try this:

`A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
    B=[["a","b"],["c","d"]]
    C = []
    for each in B:
        for evey in A:
            C.append([evey, each])
    print C`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone:Thanks for your suggestion :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to achieve this.

```
import itertools

list(itertools.product(A,B))  # gives the desired result    
[([1, 2], ['a', 'b']),
 ([1, 2], ['c', 'd']),
 ([3, 4], ['a', 'b']),
 ([3, 4], ['c', 'd']),
 ([5, 6], ['a', 'b']),
 ([5, 6], ['c', 'd'])]
```

> itertools.product(*iterables[, repeat])

It returns the Cartesian product of input iterables
**Eg.**
 `product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy`